# Converting Image to BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm having an image on disk. I want to convert it to a BufferedImage so that i can apply filters on it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [ImageIO.read(File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) . It returns BufferedImage :

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Use class "javax.imageio.ImageIO" like

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\image\\mypic.jpg"));
```

Also refer this link

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/converting-images

Comment: Thanks Parvel :), But we both seems to be on same line.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to convert a regular `Image` to a `BufferedImage` is just creating a new `BufferedImage` and painting the `Image` on it, like so:

```
Image original = ...;

BufferedImage b_img = new BufferedImage(original.getWith(), original.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ARGB);
// or use any other fitting type

b_img.getGraphics().drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
```

This may not be the best way regarding performance, but it is sure to always work.

Answer (score 0):

Java 2D™ supports loading these external image formats into its **BufferedImage** format using its `Image I/O API` which is in the `javax.imageio` package. Image I/O has built-in support for GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP.

To load an image from a specific file use the following code:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: Better to not mention exception handling, than botch it!  Call `e.printStackTrace()`